# What is the difference between Edubuntu and Ubuntu?

Tags: edubuntu

I have always used Edubuntu rather than Ubuntu because I have many children including home educated ones who casually use the education offerings. I appreciate many but not all of the extra offerings.  I never got beyond 8.04.4 LTS, so am considering updating. I note now with Edubuntu 12.04 it is >2GB i.e.4 times bigger, even apparently using squashfs.  I do now have to consider whether the extra resources are worth it in each computer in my household.

I am sick of reading over and over again 'Edubuntu is Ubuntu with extras such as blah blah', and in a different place the same thing but with a different blah blah.  I downloaded Edubuntu 12.04 and ran it 'live'.

Can't say I got on at all with the Unity Interface (this can be changed when installed), but the apparent education stuff seemed quite small and pathetic, I am obviously not finding it.  Is there anywhere a FULL LIST of what Edubuntu has pre-installed has over Ubuntu, so a sensible decision can be made whether to go for it, or just add packages that look relevant to me to Ubuntu.

Is there truly no other difference between Ubuntu/Edubuntu  but the extra educational packages? (I for example have no school server, but if I understood exactly what is involved, with the number of computers in the house, it may be worth creating one!)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Edubuntu website](http://edubuntu.org/) has a FAQ on this that points to a virtual tour so it might be a bit easier to see what Edubuntu is all about:

> [Take the tour of Edubuntu](http://www.edubuntu.org/vmmanager). There are many school-related applications installed by default, including TuxPaint, TuxMath, and TuxTyping, among others. Edubuntu can also refer to the Classroom LTSP server, which is a thin client based system.

And indeed, Edubuntu is Ubuntu with some extra packages specifically targeted on education for young people. You can yourself install Ubuntu, add these 4 packages and except for the background you should have Edubuntu installed:

> Packages

- ubuntu-edu-preschool - Preschool (< 5 years old)

  - blinken   KDE version of the Simon electronic memory game
  - gamine     an interactive game for young children
  - [gcompris](http://gcompris.net/-en-) Educational games for small children
  - kanagram    jumble word puzzle for KDE
  - khangman   Hangman word puzzle for KDE
  - ktuberling    stamp drawing toy
  - tuxpaint   A paint program for young children
- ubuntu-edu-primary - Primary (ages 6-12)

  - celestia-gnome     real-time visual space simulation (GNOME frontend)
  - [gcompris](http://gcompris.net/-en-)     Educational games for small children
  - kalzium    periodic table and chemistry tools for KDE
  - kanagram     jumble word puzzle for KDE
  - kbruch     fraction learning aid for KDE
  - khangman     Hangman word puzzle for KDE
  - kig     interactive geometry tool for KDE
  - kmplot     mathematical function plotter for KDE
  - ktouch     touch typing tutor for KDE
  - ktuberling    stamp drawing toy
  - kturtle    Logo educational programming environment for KDE
  - kwordquiz    flashcard learning program for KDE
  - laby    Learn how to program with ants and spider webs
  - lybniz    mathematical function graph plotter
  - marble    globe and map widget
  - parley    vocabulary trainer for KDE
  - ri-li    a toy train simulation game
  - stellarium    real-time photo-realistic sky generator
  - step    interactive physical simulator for KDE
  - tuxmath    math game for kids with Tux
  - tuxpaint    A paint program for young children
  - tuxtype    Educational Typing Tutor Game Starring Tux
- ubuntu-edu-secondary - Secondary (ages 13-18)

  - calibre    e-book converter and library management
  - celestia-gnome    real-time visual space simulation (GNOME frontend)
  - dia-gnome    Diagram editor (GNOME version)
  - inkscape    vector-based drawing program
  - kalzium    periodic table and chemistry tools for KDE
  - kbruch    fraction learning aid for KDE
  - kig    interactive geometry tool for KDE
  - kmplot    mathematical function plotter for KDE
  - ktouch    touch typing tutor for KDE
  - ktuberling    stamp drawing toy
  - kturtle    Logo educational programming environment for KDE
  - kwordquiz    flashcard learning program for KDE
  - laby    Learn how to program with ants and spider webs
  - lightspeed    Shows how objects moving at relativistic speeds look like
  - lybniz    mathematical function graph plotter
  - marble    globe and map widget
  - melting   compute the melting temperature of nucleic acid duplex
  - parley    vocabulary trainer for KDE
  - pencil    animation/drawing software
  - ri-li    a toy train simulation game
  - stellarium   real-time photo-realistic sky generator
  - step    interactive physical simulator for KDE
- ubuntu-edu-tertiary - Tertiary (university level)

  - calibre     e-book converter and library management
  - celestia-gnome     real-time visual space simulation (GNOME frontend)
  - dia-gnome     Diagram editor (GNOME version)
  - inkscape     vector-based drawing program
  - kalzium     periodic table and chemistry tools for KDE
  - kmplot     mathematical function plotter for KDE
  - ktouch     touch typing tutor for KDE
  - kturtle     Logo educational programming environment for KDE
  - laby     Learn how to program with ants and spider webs
  - lightspeed     Shows how objects moving at relativistic speeds look like
  - lybniz     mathematical function graph plotter
  - marble     globe and map widget
  - melting     compute the melting temperature of nucleic acid duplex
  - pencil     animation/drawing software
  - stellarium     real-time photo-realistic sky generator
  - step     interactive physical simulator for KDE
  - yorick     interpreted language and scientific graphics

> More information

- [edubuntu.org](http://edubuntu.org/screenshots) has some screenshots.
- [edu.kde.org](http://edu.kde.org/applications/all/) has an application overview with screenshots.