# How to install Edubuntu from normal Ubuntu

Tags: edubuntu

Question is, do I need to download the full 2GB Edubuntu .iso file, or can I just add something to Ubuntu?

The instructions vary depending on which page one reads

Using the Ubuntu Software Center I added the Preschool package (from regular Ubuntu), which is outlined here: https://www.edubuntu.org/download

But I don't know what to do next...

Thanks, my internet isn't that fast so if I can skip the additional 2GB DL, plus having to partition or something, that would be preferred

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and enter

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then once you're sure all your repositories are up to date enter

```
sudo apt-get install edubuntu-desktop
```

Doing that **should** get you the Edubuntu desktop, as installing the other desktops from a default Ubuntu install are pretty much the same, just with the name of the desktop, such as

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

to install Xubuntu on top of a default Ubuntu install, or

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

to install the Kubuntu desktop on top a default Ubuntu install

Comment: are you supposed to run "sudo apt-get autoremove ubuntu-desktop" after this?

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to download the 2 GB iso file. Please see the answer to this question for more details.
[What is the difference between Edubuntu and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153660/what-is-the-difference-between-edubuntu-and-ubuntu?rq=1)