# Is there a project to motivate schools to use Ubuntu?

Tags: community, education, promotion

Is there any global or EU project for motivating schools to use Ubuntu and Linux in general?

I'm trying to find a way to better motivate my co-workers in primary school to use Ubuntu in our small country.

I did migrate most of them in school to Ubuntu about a year and a half ago. And to motivate them, and show that they are doing something special, I would love to say to them "*Because you were all so brave to switch from MS to Linux, our school is now a part of [some big name project]...blabla...TV, reporters...*"

So basically I'm searching for something like [MS "innovative" schools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/education/school-leaders/create-innovative-schools/default.aspx).

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if there isn't such a thing already, then let's make one...

Comment: @Zanna That's an awesome idea, let's make one...

Comment: Related ?: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Education/UbuntuSchools and http://askubuntu.com/questions/37297/schools-and-ubuntu

Comment: @miharix: We need leap-frog devices in order to defeat old MS style of computing.

Comment: Well I don't know if this answer will be of any use but in my country schools are not using Linux because almost all of the business here use Windows (apart from the tech orientated companies). That was the main reason they gave me when I asked why they were still buying Windows activation keys.

Comment: I'll just throw this name out here @MarkShuttleworth - could be interested in this question

Comment: Voting to close this as off topic, as while it is technical "about Ubuntu," it's really a business development question about Canonical. You really need to contact Canonical directly for such questions.

Comment: @Briam - regarding your edit: the OP does not seem to be asking about Canonical programs specifically / exclusively, but also other ones, such as government or community driven endeavors as well. I don't think your edit to the title is entirely correct - I think the OP is not looking only for initiatives by Canonical, but others too.

Comment: @JonasCz well, here we talk about Ubuntu and Canonical, what other programs are doing outside what Canonical promotes makes the question *too broad* and outside the *scope*. I'm trying to savage the question, otherwise I would been voting to close.

Comment: The main issue with Linux desktops in schools/enterprises is that the management tools don't come anywhere close to what proprietary options (Active Directory) can offer. Until that is resolved there's no point in trying.

Comment: Just tell them the cost of Windows or Mac. Then tell them that 'you can have all these for FREE if you use Ubuntu/Linux'. Then they will respond - 'WTF...you gotta be kidding...lol.' Then you boot up your laptop and show them how Ubuntu rocks!!

Comment: There are many local projects in Italy (of course they are small so they don't hit the news abroad, [example](http://zoringroup.com/blog/2016/04/29/the-city-of-vicenza-is-choosing-zorin-os/)). Some famous cases are known also from several big EU cities. Unfortunately, the idea of making a big project for the whole EU seems a bit harder.

Comment: As a side note, I find really astonishing that the Microsoft FUD program reached even some comments on this question.

Comment: Hi Miharix, I have been able to get in touch with canonical. Kindly get in touch with me at parto254@gmail.com and I will give you their contact details.

Answer (score 31):

The closest I have come up with is [Ubuntu Insights case studies for schools.](https://insights.ubuntu.com/?s=school)
I would advise you to [contact Canonical](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/contact-us) directly on this and see how they can help out.

#### Edubuntu:

The [edubuntu](https://www.edubuntu.org/) project is a grassroots movement, that aims to get Ubuntu into schools, homes and communities and make it easy for users to install and maintain their systems.

This is Ubuntu but specifically for schools and comes pre-installed with many school-related applications installed including TuxPaint, TuxMath, and TuxTyping, among others.

1. https://www.edubuntu.org/
2. [What is the difference between Edubuntu and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153660/what-is-the-difference-between-edubuntu-and-ubuntu)

Other Nice links to check out:

1. http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/education
2. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Education/UbuntuSchools
3. https://schoolforge.net/

Comment: How many days does it normally take, when someone contacts Canonical ?

Comment: @miharix They have never replied?

Comment: Hey @jorge-castro is there any way you can help here?

Comment: @Pato I did write quite later as writing main question, because I was waiting if some better answer pops out. I did write around 7 or 14 days ago from now (I think, I lost little track of time.) Also filing the formular didn't send any auto response to my e-mail.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about any global programmes, In my community (Kerala, a state in southern India) there is a government project for school students known as 'IT@school' which supports use of open source softwares . IT@school  has customized versions of ubuntu OS which are used in every government and government-aided schools across Kerala , So I know that every students of my generation are aware about ubuntu and linux in my community and computer systems in nearly every homes run both windows and ubuntu as a dual boot system.

Comment: No wonder why Kerala has such high human resource development index, thumbs up from West Bengal, where anybody barely knows about Linux other than the professors and teachers

Answer (score 1):

Canonical states "We promote the use of open source in education leading to large-scale desktop migrations covering hundreds of thousands of machines" on the [about page.](http://www.canonical.com/about) There's a <kbd>Contact Us</kbd> button on the [Ubuntu For Education page](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/education)

And if all else fails, the main switchboard number found on the [about page](http://www.canonical.com/about) is +44 20 7630 2400.

Although I can't guarantee you'll get a reply, I would begin here.

Alternatively you could simply say "*Because you were so brave as to switch from MS to Linux, our school is now a part of:*"

**A global success in education**

[image: global-education]

Getting the reporters interested however is beyond my skill set.

While out of date, [this page](http://www.linfo.org/edu_resources.html) has some Linux in education related info and some of the links are still active.

Answer (score 0):

### A school based system for Linux already exists

Like many other Linux Distributions Ubuntu is based on Debian. Debian has an educational platform for schools based on `Skolelinux` where `Skole` is the Norwegian name for **School**.

From this page: ([DebianEdu Introduction - What is it?](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianEdu/Introduction#What_is_it.3F)) you see:

- **Create a complete solution:** provide a complete educational software
  solution suitable for real scenarios, entirely free.
- **Reduce technical barriers:** The best way to reach wide spread is by
  easing installation, use, maintenance and administration. We make it
  easy and working out-of-the-box.
- **International scale:** as part of a collaborative project, it is
  essential to offer as higher native translation level as possible.
- **Educational software ecosystem:** it is necessary to locate, package
  and classify any educational free software.
- **Teaching documentation:** it is important not only to provide a great
  platform but to provide documentation on how to better use it for
  teaching.

To achieve your objectives the first step would be join this programme. Later on you can see which Ubuntu or Ubuntu-like components you can embed into your environment without violating licensing agreements, ie the `non-free software`.

To get to the main **DebianEdu** click ([here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianEdu/))